# Starting DC Pump with Arduinowhen it is powered by 9v Battery

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, battery

I'm using Arduino Mega, and would like to start a DC Motor Pump. In my circuit, there are several sensors that are going to take up the voltage offered by Mega.
Hence, I would like to know whether there is a **way to control the working (start/stop) of the pump using arduino as the controller while the motor being powered by a 9V battery**.

Comment: use a relay to turn the power on off.  This gives you control over the pump, as well as isolates it from the micro-controller

Comment: A 9V battery doesn't give very much current and doesn't give any for very long.  They're usually not good for motors.  Generally AA or AAA would be better.

Comment: Thanks, So is there any way to reduce the complexity of the circuit as we don't have space for the relay module! We simply need a switch that gets ON upon Arduino's signal

Comment: How strong is your pump? An optocoppler or a simple transistor are smaller alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, its of 3.3V. I've connected it to my accessible motor driver shield of Adafruit v1. Hence I am able to switch it on or off just as any other DC Motor!!.